# ie conditional comments need explanation

Tags: html, internet-explorer

The following code is for reliable cross-browser IE version detection

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><body class="ie_6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><body class="ie_7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><body class="ie_8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><body class="ie_9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<body>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

What I don't understand is, why it's working.Why the normal `<body>` didn't overwrite the `<body class="ie_9">` since it is just a normal tag, should be recognized by all the browsers.

What's the magic about

```
    <!-->
    <body>
    <!--
```

Comment: Explained a bit more about "the magic" in an edit to my answer, after you accepted it, so I'm just putting this here to make sure you see that :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want to change `!(IE)` to `(!IE)`

Also, the "normal" `<body>` tag you're talking about is in a conditional comment. The fact that it's on a different line doesn't matter, it's still inside the conditional comment tag, so is affected as such.

Conditional comments for IE work by using normal HTML comments `<!-- -->` so any code inside a "false" conditional is just commented out; `<!-- <body class="ie6"> -->` IE then has its own syntax inside of that. As such, non-IE browsers just see a commented string, and IE treats it as a statement to execute.

Because of this, only one body tag shows, and only that one gets used.

---

More explanation of

```
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<body>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

To IE, this says:

```
<if greater than ie9, or not ie> (ie conditional comment)
<!--> (empty comment) (--> putting this here to stop SO ruining syntax highlighting :D)
<body>
<end if> (ie conditional comment)
```

If you don't understand why, read the paragraph starting "Conditional comments for IE work...".

This same block, to any other browser looks like this:

```
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> (this is just one comment, containing the text "[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!")
<body>
<!--<![endif]--> (again, just one comment, containing "<![endif]")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<body>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

means: Ouput the `<body>` there if the browser version is greater than (`gt`) IE9 (so, e.g. IE10) or if it is not IE.

Since IE9 is currently the latest version, this condition is not fulfilled by any IE.

The trick is that `-->` in the first line will close the comment in other browsers, so for them, `<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->` is just a normal comment (same for `<!--` at the last line).

But IE will parse `<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]>` and `<![endif]-->`, and treat `<!--><body><!--` as the content of the conditional comment. Which means, that if the condition is fulfilled, it outputs an empty comment, the `<body>` tag, and beginning of a comment.

MSDN has a comprehensive description about [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It seems you could achieve the same by using *Downlevel-revealed Conditional Comments*:

```
<![if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]>
<p>Please upgrade to Internet Explorer version 8.</p>
<![endif]>
```

(though it is not valid HTML).

Comment: `<body>` should be just a normal tag, should recongnized by all the browsers,regardless version or manufacture

Comment: Good answer. Just to add that the reason you need the additional `-->` and `<!--` either side of the body tag is so that non IE browsers (which just ignore conditional comments) still put the `body` tag in.

Comment: `<body>` is **NOT** commneted

Comment: @wukong: It's still inside *conditional comments*.