# position fixed issue while assigning bottom property in IE8

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I created a Chat application, I kept the parent div related to chat application as `position:fixed`. here is the excerpt code:

```
#chat-outline
{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 16%;
    height: 45%;
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-height: 450px;
    max-width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 25px;  //even tried by giving 'em', no use
    right: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

The problem is that in IE8, I need to give more value to `bottom` property to make it completely visible(the below part is cutting down). If I do so, In chrome, the chat application is going more top than usual.

Any fix to this?

I am doing this in asp.net so, there is no need to worry about doctype.(as it provides the template)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

EDIT:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <title></title>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="JSfiles/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <!--[if lte IE 8 ]><html class="ie_8"><![endif]-->
     <!--[if (gt IE 8)|(!IE)]><!-->
        <html>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="#chat-outline"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried giving bottom in %?

Comment: [How to Target IE6, IE7, and IE8 Uniquely with 4 Characters](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts That link recommends conditional comments. anyway thank you for the link :)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts This is true however to allow validation I would prefer `<!--[if lte IE 8 ]>...<![endif]-->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a conditional HTML class for IE8. Change your `<html>` tag to this

```
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]><html class="ie_8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|(!IE)]><!-->
<html>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

and then in your css have this

```
.ie_8 #chat-outline {
    bottom: 25px  //OR whatever it needs to be
}
```

This will mean that the increased bottom will not affect any other browser:

See here for more info: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358716/ie-conditional-comments-need-explaination)

**EDIT**

Your html is invalid:

Try This:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie_8">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|(!IE)]><!-->
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <title></title>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="JSfiles/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="#chat-outline"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Mr_Green It has worked for me in the past, I havent got a link to your site so i cannot test it.

Comment: This isn't working.. checked with "inspect element" still bottom is 25px instead of 55px

Comment: do you have a link? I'll take a look

Comment: No I dont, Can you please make sample html with the css I provided and try it..?

Comment: i would need a html markup to do that, can you provide me with it?

Comment: I didnt get you.. If you mean `doctype` then it is in the post.

Comment: yeah worked.. It was working from the first post of yours. I havent seen that you are typing `.ie8` instead of `.ie_8` in the css.  Correct it.. :D. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reset the documents padding and margin?

CSS:

```
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
    <style>
    div {
       bottom: /* as you want */;
    }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: It should work but it's inline styling that would be the only issue i can see

Comment: I did that because otherwise, he will need a separate .css file to link it to HTML.

Comment: not necessarily if you use conditional classes i.e. : `<html class="ie_8">` instead of a `<link rel` etc. then you can add it to the existing one.

Comment: Oh Yes That Could Be The Way! Thanks :D