# Preventing a line of html from appearing in Google search

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, search-engine

Within all my html pages, I have a paragraph as follows:

```
<p class="IE_Message">Please update your browser to enjoy the content of this website.</p>
```

This is only displayed when users are using IE 8 or less. My issue is that whenever I search for the website in google, and my search contains the word 'website', this line shows up in the description of the page.

I've tried this:

```
<!--googleoff: index-->
    <p class="IE_Message">Please update your browser to enjoy the content of this website.</p>
<!--googleon: index-->
```

It didn't work.

Any ideas as to how to go about this?

How would I go about loading the text via javascript? I did try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".IE_Message").text("Please update your browser to enjoy the content of this website.");
});
```

But the text didn't show when I tested it.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using conditional comments (`<!--[if lt IE 9]> HTML here <![endif]-->`)? As other browsers interpret them as HTML comments, they (probably) shouldn't show up in Google. The shown conditional comment would hide the contents for every browser, except those that are Internet Explorer versions less than (`lt`) IE 9.

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358716/ie-conditional-comments-need-explaination) (Felix Kling's answer might suit your needs)

Comment: I've used the conditional statements and the line still appears in the description?

Comment: Consider removing the text. It adds no value to your site, and it is more or less an insult to users who simply cannot update their browser due to company policy. If you still feel compelled to give such “advice”, add it with JavaScript. There is little need for jQuery in a simple case like this. And don’t expect the change to get reflected in Google anytime soon. It may take months before they decide to re-index a page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional comments here. It will not appear in google.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    Please update your browser to enjoy the content of this website.
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: `if lt IE 9` would be what OP is looking for.

Comment: I've used the conditional statements and the line still appears in the description?

Comment: Does google cache the description or something? I've even deleted the line from every page and it's still showing?

Comment: Use `<meta name="description" content="A description of the page" />`. So, This text only will be shown in google description.

Comment: @Forrest : Yes, Google might cache the description. Please check after sometime.