# prevent angular from loading on an unsupported browser

Tags: angularjs, legacy

I'm developing a web app using angular and [angular mobile UI](http://mobileangularui.com/)

Angular 1.3.0 dropped support for Internet Explore 8, and even though I could use version 1.2.9 angular mobile UI doesn't support IE 8 either.

So I was wondering what would be the cleanest and safest way to catch when the user is using and unsupported browser and redirect him to a page telling him to go and download a real web browser.

Comment: For Internet Explorer, you can use conditionnal comment. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358716/ie-conditional-comments-need-explaination) might help you in doing so.