# Display different page when loading Nuxt.js page on older browsers (IE11)

Tags: nuxt.js

After failing to get my nuxt.js app working on IE11 (probably due to an incorrectly transpired dependency), I am searching for a solution to show a different webpage when loading the page in IE 11.

The problem is that according to IE11 my JS contains a syntax error, so I'm searching for a solution that I can program into the app.html file. I've tried the following code in app.html to run a script that then changes the content of the `head` and `body` attribute automatically.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    <script>
      function isIE() {
          const ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
          const msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
          const trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
          return (msie > 0 || trident > 0);
        }
      if (isIE()) {
        document.write('<body>oudebrowser</body>')
      } else {
        document.head.innerHTML = "{{ HEAD }}"
        document.write('<body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>{{ APP }}</body>')
      }
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

The problem is that I cannot escape the contents of the `{{ HEAD }}` variable, so I'm afraid this attempted solution leads to a dead end.

Comment: I use the <script type="module" src="/path"><script> for supported browsers and <script nomodule src="/path"></script> for not supported browsers like IE11. And modify the content in nuxt.config.js and app.html accordingly. The content of {{ HEAD }} should come from nuxt.config.js.

Comment: Well, I figured it out, the problem was that one of the modules was not working with IE. So I had to add it to the build.transpile in nuxt.config.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) to set the browsers you're expecting Babel to transpile to.

You also can try magic comments but I do not recommend it since it will be done in the HTML directly: [ie conditional comments need explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7358716/8816585)

Also, IE is currently *deprecated* by Microsoft itself. On top of a lot of companies already not supporting it already. So, if you do not have a lot of cash incoming from some IE users only, you should probably stop supporting IE too: https://death-to-ie11.com

Just drop it and aim for faster, better and less heavy web app experiences.

PS: Vue3 is not supporting IE already too.